# Static Content deploy parallel jobs is not working in Docker

Tags: static-content, static-content-deploy, docker

When using --jobs=4 or -j=4 with setup:static-content:deploy command its working on my local machine and it build the assets in parallel

but when using this command inside a docker container with php:7.1-fpm Official docker image - its only build a single task at the same time.

Any idea?